# Sync Redis key from ConfigMap

Tags: redis

I have a ConfigMap in Kubernetes that contains a file (specifically a CaddyFile). I need to automatically synchronize this file to a specific key in Redis. Is there anyone who knows how to accomplish this task?
Thank you